# Rspec no Method error assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I apparently added a new field to my Customer model known as ct_ratio before running tests. When I now run tests on my invoice spec, they fail with a "No method error,ct_ratio="

Customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :billing_address, :customer_currency, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :mobile,  :name, :payment_terms, :phase_type, :readings_attributes, :pays_vat, :ct_ratio
  before_validation do
 self.ct_ratio ||= 1
 end
end
```

Invoice_spec

```
describe Invoice do

context 'create_item_from_readings' do
before :each do
  @customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
  @reading1 = @customer.readings.create! reading1: 100, date_of_reading: 30.days.ago
  @reading2 = @customer.readings.create! reading1: 200, date_of_reading: 20.days.ago
  @reading3 = @customer.readings.create! reading1: 500, date_of_reading: 10.days.ago
  @customer.stub(:unit_cost).and_return(100)
end

it "should create an invoice item for all reading" do
  invoice = Invoice.new customer: @customer, invoice_date: 15.days.ago, due_date: Date.today

  item = invoice.create_item_from_readings
  item.rate.should   == 100
  item.amount.should == 100 * 100
  item.description.should == "Electricity used from #{@reading1.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} to #{@reading2.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} -    100 units"
end
```

I added ct_ratio to Factory Girl

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do

 factory :customer do
 name 'Test Test'
 first_name "Test"
 last_name "Test"
 mobile "00000000"
 billing_address "Kampala"
 payment_terms "Immediate"
 phase_type "Single Phase"
 customer_currency "UGX"
 pays_vat false
 email "test@test.com"
 ct_ratio 1
end

factory :reading do |f|
 f.reading1 100
 f.reading2 150
 f.reading3 200
 f.date_of_reading 30.days.ago
end

end
```

Comment: You "*apparently* added a new field"? Did you add it or did you not add it?

Comment: @shioyama I added a new field ct_ratio and added it to factory girl too

Answer (score 0):

this is a common error when not running tests via `rake` and your migration is not run on the test-database.

run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` first and check out your testsuite.

Comment: How should I check my test suite